# Erase a lineTo line in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have this file http://www.rebuild.co.za/temp/lineDraw.fla Basically lines gets drawn where ever I tween the animation.arrow MovieClip. What I'm wanting to do is be able to rewind the MovieClip and have the line erase its self step by step.

If any one knows of an easier way to do line animations please tell me.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your flash file, you probably want each line to be drawn in a separate MovieClip which is then pushed into an array.  When you reverse you can just pop the last MovieClip from the array and remove it from the stage.

Comment: That's a really bad idea because you're going to end up piling up a ton of work for the already-bad garbage collector to do.

Comment: Thanks shanethehat, I will give it a bash.

Comment: @Ascension Systems - It's not ideal, but the only alternative I could think of was to store the coordinates to each lineTo() call in the array instead, but that would involve emptying the graphics object and redrawing every line instead.

Comment: @shanethehat the array way is better or even better a Vector

Comment: sure, a vector is better for collections of the same data type. Good point.

Comment: Or you could clone the graphics object and push that to a vector. The graphics object is a much lighter class than a MovieClip (it's extended directly from Object) and because of it's nature it should be one of the easiest objects for the garbage collector to handle. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#copyFrom()

Comment: At the very least use `Shape` instead of `MovieClip`. `Sprite` at the outside if you need mouse interaction. That, or keep the coordinates in an Array/Vector and just draw them to one `Shape`. To delete a line, delete the coord and redraw

Comment: @Ascension Systems - +1, that is a much better approach.

Comment: The level of effort should be tailored to the scale of the problem. If we're talking dozens to hundreds of lines, drawing each one into a MovieClip is probably fine. If it's thousands, grouping them 50 (or whatever) per Sprite might be better. If it must scale arbitrarily, the lowest lines could be drawn into a bitmap as they accrue. But based on the supplied FLA, it doesn't look likely that scalability will be an issue.

Comment: Also @Ascension Systems, your suggestion doesn't make sense. You can't directly create instances of `Graphics` at runtime, they are created or collected together with the display objects they are attached to. `CopyFrom` is used between two existing instances. Also, the GC doesn't come into this - it doesn't treat basic display objects any differently than movieclips, it's all down to how you manage your references.

Comment: Well for starters yes the GC certainly does come into it here. First of all if you don't think theres any significant difference in class size and memory allocation between a class with 1 level of inheritance and a class with 6 levels, then I'm curious to hear that explanation. Also the GC comes into play because of the nature of the object. We're talking the difference between a generic object and a display list object. By nature the very moment that display object is created it's attaching at least 3 listeners and checking for a reference to the stage and other display objects constantly.

Comment: So yes, absolutely the GC comes into play for the very reason you mention: references. And second of all, although you are right that you cannot directly instantiate the graphics object with the classes available to you by default, you're wrong to tell me that I cannot at all or even that my comment doesn't make sense. In 10-15 minutes tops using alchemy I could have a module for cloning and creating an instance (yes instances, not references) of Graphics objects.

Comment: So you're suggesting it would be a good idea for the questioner to use alchemy? Rather than simply keeping a vector of numbers or `Shape`s? To what benefit?